# “Microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0” provider not registered issue after October Windows Patching

Tags: windows, vb.net, ssis, connection-string, sql-server-data-tools

Due to the recent Windows Patching in October 2017, we had seen that one of our SSIS Script task designed with VB.net 2010 used to fetch data from SQL Server and create an excel (.xls) file and populate it with the same has stopped working.

The excel connectionString used here is:

`excelConString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & strFileName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;"""`

We were getting

```
"Unexpected error from external database driver (1)"**, post which we had modified the string to:

excelConString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & strFileName & ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=YES;ReadOnly=False;';"
```

In our case, we copied the SSIS Script code and pasted the script to a button call function for debugging it in a Windows Form Solution in Visual Studio 2013. We also modified the Target Platform to x64.

The excel was getting generated fine as expected.

However, in case we are trying to update the connection string in the SSIS Script Task Editor in SSDT for Visual Studio 2015, we are still getting the error The `'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'` provider is not registered on the local machine."

We had modified the Target platform in the Script Task solution by removing the "Any CPU" option so that only the created x64 option is available.

If anyone can please help with this issue, it would really be a great help.

We had already tried the AccessDatabaseEngine.exe drivers installation, but we can see that the Windows Form Solution is able to fix the issue in Production environment system itself where no drivers were installed. Only the x64 Target platform and connectionString modification is done. Why then is it not working when done in the SSIS script task.

Comment: Switching the platform from Any CPU to x64 is unlikely to be helpful.  If there is a problem with the platform it is usually because there is only a 32-bit provider installed and the app is running in a 64-bit process.  A platform of x64 won't change that on a 64-bit machine. It simply means that it won't run at all on a 32-bit machine. You need to set the platform to x86 for force the app to run in a 32-bit process so it can access a 32-bit provider. The alternative would be to install 64-bit ACE.

Comment: Hi, I tried changing it to x86 but I'm still getting the "'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine." message.

Comment: I may not have read your question carefully enough in the first place. You're saying that a WinForms app targeting the x64 platform on that same machine works but your SSIS package tells you that ACE is not installed, correct? In that case, it sounds like the SSIS package is being executed in a 32-bit process. I'm not sure how that's controlled to be honest but I would guess that it would depend on whether you installed 32-bit or 64-bit SQL Server. Is that a possible cause?

Comment: I am not sure really...i believe a x62 version of SQL Server is installed.

Answer (score 0):

i know that an x64 version of SQL Server is installed.
i did manage to get the issue rectified by changing the SSIS package content. Instead of using a script task, i used an Execute Process Task. I converted the script task code to a vb console application. In the console application, I changed the target platform to x64 and used the exe file created. This helped in getting the excel generated correctly. 
Thanks.